# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating custom components of select and facing some issues.
Showing this error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
I want to map select option and use in pages from props

```
function CustomSelect(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const options = [
    "Religion", 
    "Internal ", 
    "Not Profit", 
  ];
  const {
    age,
    setAge,
    list
  } = props;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl variant="filled" className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-filled"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
        {list.map(item => (
            <MenuItem value="test">
                {item.options}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you passing list (as in array) from parent component?

Comment: Can you show your list array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` is passed as a prop, so in this situation you should probably provide a default value.

```
function CustomSelect(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const options = [
    "Religion", 
    "Internal ", 
    "Not Profit", 
  ];
  const {
    age,
    setAge,
    list = [], // <-- provide an initial value if undefined
  } = props;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl variant="filled" className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-filled"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
        {list.map(item => (
            <MenuItem value="test">
                {item.options}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

You should probably also define propTypes so you can ensure the correct type is passed.

[Typechecking with PropTypes](http://CustomSelect)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

CustomSelect.propTypes = {
  list: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

If you can, be as specific as possible

```
list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  options: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}))
```

The `.isRequired` bit will throw a warning in non-production builds that the `list` prop is undefined or otherwise ***not*** been passed.

Comment: yes, this error is resolved to thank you. but options array not get in map list

Comment: @TusharKumawat Can you provide what an `item.options` object shape is? i.e. what is it you're trying to render there with it?